# How can I rename Web Api Bearer Token ".expires" key?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, jwt, bearer-token

A response from /Token returns a payload that looks something like this:

```
"access_token":"foo",
"token_type":"bearer",
"expires_in":59,
"refresh_token":"bar",
".issued":"Sat, 17 Sep 2016 00:13:21 GMT",
".expires":"Sat, 17 Sep 2016 00:14:21 GMT"
```

Is there a reason .issued and .expired named they way they are? These are not valid JavaScript properties so I intend to rename them. If there a more elegant way to do this besides overriding the `TokenEndpoint` method like this:

```
public override Task TokenEndpoint(OAuthTokenEndpointContext context)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> property in context.Properties.Dictionary)
    {
        string key = property.Key;
        switch (key)
        {
            case ".expires":
                key = "expires";
                break;
            case ".issued":
                key = "issued";
                break;
        }
        context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add(key, property.Value);
    }
    return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
}
```

An example of why I want to do this. I like to provide a TypeScript interface that mimics the data I expect to receive from a request. In this case, my interface looks like this:

```
interface IToken {
    .expires: string;        // Not valid TypeScript
    .issued: string;         // Not valid TypeScript
    access_token: string;
    expires_in: number;
    token_type: string;
    refresh_token: string;
}
```

Without changing the property in my API, I and others using my API are forced to access these properties using magic strings like `tokenVar[".expires"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a specific reason to do that. It's just another constant used. See AuthenticationProperties.cs here https://github.com/jchannon/katanaproject/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Owin/Security/AuthenticationProperties.cs

As in your code overriding `TokenEndpoint` method of `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider` is the best way to go about it.

Comment: I edited my question to provide an example of why I would want to do this.

Comment: Yes I understood that part but as I mentioned overriding `TokenEndpoint` is the only way to go about it which you are already doing.